# Route stereo audio from channel 1->3 & 2->4 using 4-channel sound interface

Tags: audio, driver, mirroring

How can I mirror the stereo audio output on output channels 1 & 2 to channels 3 & 4 on my 4-channel sound interface (Focusrite Scarlett 2i4) using free software without adding more cables?

Currently I am successfully mapping channel 1 to 3 and channel 2 to 4 with the trial version of Rogue Amoeba Loopback, but the trial version only lasts 20 minutes.

I have tried to do this with "Audio MIDI Setup" but it is not supported. Bear in mind this is on a 2012 Macbook Air locked to macOS 10.9, so it cannot be upgraded (ever).

Comment: "locked to macOS 10.9" - no Mac tops out at 10.9. The 2012 should be good to Catalina.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe I'm doing something wrong but I've tried to upgrade several times and it fails every time.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos [which is in the process of being updated… again] 10.9 probably can't see the App Store properly these days. You might have to go to EL Cap, then High Sierra before you can jump to Ctalina [With caveat, Catalina will no longer run anything 32 bit, so you *may* want to stop at Mojave if you rely on anything that can't be updated.]

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this as Rogue Amoeba Loopback costs $114 and I can't afford it.

Comment: [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) might be able to do this. I haven't tested it, as I already own all the Rogue Amoeba stuff.

Comment: @Tetsujin unfortunately, Blackhole cannot do this.